# Trap Console Close event When the User types EXIT and press ENTER

Tags: c++, windows, console, console-application

I am modifying a console application in `C++`. I need to do some clean up when the user types `EXIT<ENTER>` or press `X` (i.e. Close) button on top right corner.

I am able to trap console exit when user presses `X` (close) button as follows:

```
case CTRL_C_EVENT:
        fprintf(stderr, "Ctrl-C is Pressed\n");
        return TRUE;
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT:
        fprintf(stderr, "Ctrl-Break is Pressed\n");
        return TRUE;

    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT:
    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:
        system(cleanup_cmd.c_str());
```

But I cannot figure out how to trap if the user types `EXIT` and press `ENTER`.

Can you please help? I did some research here on StackOverFlow. There are number of threads that ask about closing console window with `X` button. But I could not find any when user actually types `EXIT`. I apologize if it is a duplicate.

Comment: What does your program look like? How is it structured? How are you currently accepting input?

Comment: Try to avoid calling `system` - ever. It doesn't give you very much control and its use is riddled with security risks. There are always better options.

Comment: it is just a console application. @JesperJuhl what are the other options?

Comment: @Cricrazy On Unix/posix like operating systems; `fork` + one of the `exec` family of calls is *one* way to get more control (over the shell that'll run your program, its environment, its input and output etc).

Comment: I am on windows 10, and not very familiar with Unix system.

Comment: Typing `EXIT<Enter>` is not a signal and therefore it's not a handled by your snippet above - it's probably handled by some other code not shared yet. My guess is, it's getting passed on to the console as is, and console is exiting on your behalf, and some preprocessing should be done first if you wanna skip that.

Comment: *how to trap if the user types EXIT and press ENTER.* you need somehow handle user input. say call `ReadConsole` and based on string which user enter - do something

Comment: it definitely seems harder that I thought.

Comment: If the user types EXIT, how that's handled is entirely up to the program. This has nothing to do with the console, other than that the program is reading input from the console.